# Altium Designer Net Antennae Error

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-antenna

I am connecting a via to a polygon in one of the middle layers. My goal is to use it as a test point. Altium gives me a net Antennae violation. Although there are ways to silent the tool from giving this error, Is this something I should be worried about in terms of PCB performance?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what is the violation? What is the rule you have setup in rule manager?

Comment: Violation is : Net Antennae : Via from top layer to bottom layer. 
Related rule is: Design rules -> Manufacturing -> Net Antennae -> Net Antennae Tolerance: 0 mil

Comment: You can find the details about net antennae error here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-manufacturing-rule-net-antennae?version=21

Comment: I understand why Altium marks this as an error and I can manipulate the rules or manually silent this error. I was wondering if PCB experts could tell me if this is actually going to cause performance issues, or behave like an antennae even though it is only connected to a ground polygon?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your via will actually create an antenna.

The net Antenna rule in Altium is to make sure there are no stubs on critical nets. I usually use this rule constraints on high speed interface between a driver and a receiver.

In your case, AGND should not carry high speed signals. The error showed up because you have a thermal relief to your via and this via is not routed to anything (no load). On top of that, your net antenna tolerance is set up to only 0 mils. Hence, this creates a stub and a violation.

On a side note, if you want to reduce stub length on critical nets, you should try to put your test points in-line near the driver or receiver and use [backdrilling.](https://resources.altium.com/p/backdrilling)

Answer (score 1):

Altium will flag a via going to nowhere as a net antennae. You have two options:

- Right click the error and tell Altium to "waive violations", and ignore it. Altium is warning you that there might be a problem, but the PCB fabricator won't care that you have an untented via to nowhere.
- Replace the via with a pad. The pad will perform the same function as a test point, but without the error.

Comment: I mean, you can also just disable the rule, whether by deleting it, disabling it, restricting it to relevant nets/classes, or disabling the rule in Design Rule Check.